# How to use lint tools in react-native javascript development ( using Atom )?

Tags: react-native, atom-editor

How to integrate lint tools in react-native javascript development ( using Atom ) ?

Are there tools that I can integrate with Atom or Visual Studio Code ( OS X) editors that will lint and detect errors as I edit an open files?

Or can you somehow execute these tool on run?

```
react-native run-android 
react-native run-ios
```

What is is a typical work-flow when using these JS and JSX lint tools?

I would like to prevent Android exceptions such as duplicate definitions of properties or functions:

```
React com.facebook.react.bridge.JSExecutionException: SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'myPropertyName'
```

My current work flow is to grep the source for cause of the redefine exception, fix, then run on Android again, fix next exception, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes running Atom with linter-eslint: https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint will do just that for you.