# How to trace JavascriptException index.android.bundle:424:4194 to line number in JS source?

Tags: react-native, stack-trace

Google Play stack trace points the cause of crash at:

```
com.facebook.react.modules.core.JavascriptException: addWaypointDone
    index.android.bundle:424:4194
```

I extracted index.android.bundle from the apk.

How do I get a JS source code line number from **424:4194** ?

Thanks Daniel. Your approach worked for me from the command-line!

I tried adding this to android/app/react.gradle but I could not find and source.map file under the ./android directory.

```
commandLine "react-native", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}”,
"--sourcemap-output", "source.map",
"--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets dest", resourcesDir
```

Is there a way to auto-build source.map file very time?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get an exact position you need a source map. If you don't keep those for your deploys you can regenerate it.

- Check out the exact version you deployed from your VCS
- Bundle it with source map output: `react-native bundle --entry-file index.android.js --platform android --dev false --sourcemap-output source.map --bundle-output main.jsbundle` (make sure you use the exact same dependency versions you used in your release)
- Create a file `findpos.js` containing the following code:

findpos.js

```
var sourceMap = require('source-map');
var fs = require('fs');

var sourcemap = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('source.map', 'utf8'));

var smc = new sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer(sourcemap);

console.log(smc.originalPositionFor({
  line: 424,
  column: 4194
}));
```

- Execute the script `node findpos.js`

You should get the exact location of the error (file, line and column).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your apparoach worked for me from the command-line.<br />
I tried adding this to android/app/react.gradle but I could not find and source.map file under the ./android directory.
    commandLine "react-native", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}”,
    "--sourcemap-output", "source.map",
    "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir
Is there a way to auto-build source.map file very time?

Comment: At the moment you would have to copy node_modules/react-native/react.gradle to your project, add sourcemap, and use that instead of the official gradle. It's not great, but it works. Someone already created an issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7393

Comment: Thanks @Deniel I added a +1 to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7393

Comment: Daniel can you offer any tips on using lint tools so I could catch javascript property redefinitions *before* I run on Android device and it crashes?  
See my open question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447856/how-to-use-lint-tools-in-react-native-javascript-development-using-atom

Answer (score 1):

**How to use Atom to find the exception source code in the index.android.bundle**

1. Get stack trace from Google Play
2. Rename the apk file with a zip extension and extract apk
3. Using Atom or other editor, open up the extracted '''assets/index.android.bundle''
4. Edit > Go to Line , from stack trace, 424:4194

All white-space is removed from the index.android.bundle and lines are concatenated to a single line.  But it identifies the culprit.

Comment: This is genius! Thank you! And works for android bundles too (*.aab)